# Unity4 Can't use using UnityEngine.UI ;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity4 to create which I learned from Brackeys

My code isnt working, `using UnityEngine.UI;` isn't working in unity4 i think.

help me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class score : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;
    public GUIText scoreText;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        scoreText.guiText = player.position.z.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scoreText.guiText` is a type of component not `string` and it is a read-only variable. That should be `scoreText.text` because you are trying to modify the text of the GUIText.

```
public Transform player;
public GUIText scoreText;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString();
}
```

Note that Unity4 is old and `GUIText`  is now deprecated. I suggest you upgrade your Unity version and take advantage of the new UI system which uses the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component.